# Two INSERT statements with UNION in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, union

When i run the code without UNION and with one SELECT it works but when i try to run all together it wont insert data into table, or to try in different way without UNION, some help here.

```
<?php
include("conf.php");
$query = "INSERT INTO fund(Team, GamesPlayedHome, GoalsScorredHome, GoalsAcceptedHome, RedCardGotHome, AvarageGoalsScorredHome, AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome, GamesPlayedAway, GoalsScorredAway, GoalsAcceptedAway, RedCardGotAway, AvarageGoalsScorredAway, AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway)
SELECT HomeTeam As Team, COUNT(HomeTeam) AS GamesPlayedHome, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedHome, SUM(HomeRedCards) AS RedCardGotHome, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY HomeTeam ORDER BY HomeTeam ASC
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(AwayTeam) AS GamesPlayedAway, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsScorredAway, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedAway, SUM(AwayRedCards) AS RedCardGotAway, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredAway, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY AwayTeam ORDER BY AwayTeam ASC";
$data= mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
    foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
        print "$cname: $cvalue\t";
    }
    print "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The columns in the two queries for a `union` need to be the same.  Your columns are obviously not the same.  Get the `union` (`union all` is preferable) to work without the `insert`.

Comment: i tryed with `UNION ALL` but still doesn't work. And i got `PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\query.php on line 12`

Comment: In the line `or die(mysqli_error())` provide connection `mysqli_error($conn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO account(employees)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT employees FROM account WHERE id = 1
UNION
SELECT employees FROM account WHERE id = 2
) AS a
```

Wrap union result in another table.

So your query is:

```
    <?php
    include("conf.php");
    $query = "INSERT INTO fund(Team, GamesPlayedHome, GoalsScorredHome, GoalsAcceptedHome, RedCardGotHome, AvarageGoalsScorredHome, AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome, GamesPlayedAway, GoalsScorredAway, GoalsAcceptedAway, RedCardGotAway, AvarageGoalsScorredAway, AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway)
    seelct * from (SELECT HomeTeam As Team, COUNT(HomeTeam) AS GamesPlayedHome, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedHome, SUM(HomeRedCards) AS RedCardGotHome, 
    SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome
    FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY HomeTeam ORDER BY HomeTeam ASC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(AwayTeam) AS GamesPlayedAway, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsScorredAway, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedAway, SUM(AwayRedCards) AS RedCardGotAway, 
    SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredAway, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway
    FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY AwayTeam ORDER BY AwayTeam ASC) as temp";
    $data= mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
        foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
            print "$cname: $cvalue\t";
        }
        print "\r\n";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you but still no succes. i get this error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'temp' (T_STRING)`

Answer (score 0):

When using the UNION ALL the columns in the both `SELECT` query need to be same. In your given query the column list are not match.

13 columns in the `INSERT` block but for the first `SELECT` it contains 7 columns and second `SELECT` it contains 6 columns.

So you can add `NULL` or Zero (for the not null columns) for the remaining columns.

Hope you need the below query:

```sql
INSERT INTO test 
(Team, GamesPlayedHome, GoalsScorredHome, GoalsAcceptedHome, RedCardGotHome, AvarageGoalsScorredHome, AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome, 
 GamesPlayedAway, GoalsScorredAway, GoalsAcceptedAway, RedCardGotAway, AvarageGoalsScorredAway, AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway)
SELECT HomeTeam As Team, COUNT(HomeTeam) AS GamesPlayedHome, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedHome, SUM(HomeRedCards) AS RedCardGotHome, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome
, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY HomeTeam ORDER BY HomeTeam ASC)
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
COUNT(AwayTeam) AS GamesPlayedAway, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsScorredAway, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedAway, SUM(AwayRedCards) AS RedCardGotAway, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredAway, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY AwayTeam ORDER BY AwayTeam ASC
```